# Is there a way to get the document with selected content through office.js

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am working in word add-in where I want to get the document with selected content only, instead of the whole document.

There is an API for getting the whole document:

```
// Get all of the content from a PowerPoint or Word document in 100-KB chunks of text.
Office.context.document.getFileAsync("compressed",
        { sliceSize: 100000 },
        function (result) {
});
```

But I want only selected content.

Answer (score 2):

You use the [`Document.getSelectedDataAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getselecteddataasync) method:

```js
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync("Text", function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log('Action failed. Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Selected data: ' + asyncResult.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: But using the above api we will get the selected content only , I want document as file with selected content. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you use `Ooxml ` instead of `Text` you will get the OOXML for the selected content. This is the raw format used for `.docx` documents.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Is there a direct way to convert OOXML string to a '.docx' file? I am using apache POI in my java server to create a document with the current selection from client. Is it possible to convert OOXML string to a document?

Comment: @LJP have you found any solution?

Comment: @RameshPerera - I used Apache POI to convert the OOXML to document.